# Optimize SQL query across list-of-items

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-design, bitmap

I have about 400K product rows in a database. All queries on this dataset are optimized to return in under 0.4s and run well. However, I need to add an additional field called Territories, that could include anywhere from 0-250 territories (any country in the world), usually around 150. Of course the 'relational' way to add this would be to add a territory with an FKey to the product table, yet when I try that with a join, I usually get queries in the 2-7s range, as now I'm querying about 60M rows, and the query is something like:

```
SELECT product from table join ... 
WHERE territories in ['USA', 'France', 'Germany']
ORDER BY some_field LIMIT 50
```

This is way too slow for the application requirements, and I was wondering how I might be able to speed up this query using some sort of potentially flat field. Here were some ideas I had:

- Store it as a json array (tried this, performance was even worse than a join).
- Store this as a set (don't think possible, as set is [8 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) so less than 100 values).
- Do something like full-text search field and index each country as a single unit (might be ok, but very poor having to run the sort at the end)
- Use four BIGINTs with a bitmap across those four fields for the 240 values (seems like a terrible idea, but an idea I had nonetheless).

My requirement here is the query needs to return in under 0.5s. What might be the best way to do this?

Comment: So you're certain that the tables are optimally indexed?

Comment: Compare `EXPLAIN {query that fetches 1 territory}` to `EXPLAIN {above query}`.   `OR` and `IN` conditions hurt index use. Look at `UNION` to join multiple single territory queries.

Comment: The use of the `WHERE` clause probably precludes the use of an index of for the `ORDER BY`.  My guess is that is slowing down the query and there is not much you can do about it, other than perhaps filtering *after* the results are returned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see -- for that would you recommend using the relational structure? Or something else.

Comment: The `JOIN` is critical to the performance of the query; let's see the rest of the query.  Also, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.